# AWS DynamoDB table Partition Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Question about Partition Key in Dynamodb table.

It says Partition key – A simple primary key, composed of one attribute known as the partition key.

DynamoDB uses the partition key's value as input to an internal hash function. The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be stored.

Quetion:
So If I have 1 million records in a Orders table with Orderid being the partition key. Does it mean each record of my Orders table is stored in 1 million servers? How is that is possible?

Comment: Why do you think, each partition is stored on a different server?

Comment: Documentation says "Partition key represents in which partition (a group of servers) the record is saved for faster access"

Comment: That doesn't mean, that each server (group of servers) can handle only one partition, or that each partition is saved on a different server. That would be total nonsense. Imagine having a table with no orderering key, ie each partition key exists only once. That would mean every server will only hold one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash output determines the physical partition for placement.  Say you have four partitions backing the table. If the hash output value is in the first quarter of the keyspace it goes into the first partition. And so on. The hash value output will determine into which of the four it goes.

Then partitions can split as needed, each one taking a subset of the keyspace of the old.

Comment: who determines how many partitions are there for a table.  are the total number of partitions pre-determined?

Comment: Size of the data or the workload. A physical partition can only handle 10GB and 3000RCU/1000WCU.

Comment: If you're in Provisioned mode, the number of partitions is determined as appropriate for the RCU/WCU you've provisioned. If you're in On Demand mode, the number of partitions is responsive based on observed traffic. Plus you get new partitions if the 10 GB limit is passed. Really, you shouldn't have to worry so much about this stuff. These are internal details that only impact you when pushing high scale workloads. Worry less, code more. :)